# Change duplicating lines in file

Tags: text-processing

Need to find all duplicate lines in file.
For each case keep first occurrence as is, and append incremented counter to each next occurrence.

For example:

### original file

```
A
B
C
A
C
A
C
```

### need

```
A
B
C
A_2
C_2
A_3
C_3
```

Preferably answer in bash or python

Comment: Well, what have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`Awk`** is the right way:

```
awk 'a[$1]++{ $1=$1"_"a[$1] }1' file
```

The output:

```
A
B
C
A_2
C_2
A_3
C_3
```